# Setting array to null to avoid memory leaks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React component's constructor, I create array of refs like this:

```
this.tabRefs = [];
someList.forEach(item => {
   ...
   this.tabRefs.push(React.createRef());
})
```

In componentWillUnmount should I clear it like:

```
this.tabRefs = null;
```

or:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.tabRefs.length; i += 1) {
    this.tabRefs[i] = null;
}
```

Which one is better way to avoid memory leaks?

Comment: On unmount the instance is destroyed. I don't believe you need to manually mark `tabRefs` as null, since all pointers will be removed and garbage collector can do the rest

Comment: Once the component is destroyed, `this.tabRefs` will be unused, and will be freed up. There is no need to call `componentWillUnmount()` at all in this case. The answers below, are just over optimizations of something that doesn't need to be run at all.

Comment: Looks like you are right, on React Ref documentation: React will assign the current property with the DOM element when the component mounts, and assign it back to null when it unmounts.